# Añadir Base de Datos de SQL Server en IIS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, base-de-datos, asp.net-mvc, iis

Con IIS he asignado la carpeta donde esta el codigo para que ejecute la pagina web, y me lo hace correctamente.

Mi pagina web tiene como objetivo aumentar los conocimientos de Geografia en Cataluña, hay 3 actividades y cuando acabas una actividad te pide un Nick Name, ademas de guardar la Nota y el nombre de la actividad.

El problema que tengo es que necesito agregar una base de datos para guardar la informacion de las diferentes actividades (Id, Nick, Nombre Actividad, Fecha, Nota) utilizando SQL Server.

Para añadir la base de datos en IIS agrego una nueva con la siguiente información para conectarlo con el SQL Server.

[image: Añadir Base de datos en IIS]

Añadiendo ademas la linea de codigo que pone abajo en **Web.config** para que conecte con la base de datos:

[image: Linea Web.config]

Y para saber si se añadia correctamente creando una base de datos vacia en SQL Server con el nombre de **AplicacioActivitats**:

[image: SQL Server]

El problema esta en que cuando ejecuto el IIS para ver si la pagina web se conecta a la base de datos y se ve correctamente pasa lo siguiente:

[image: Error]

**Quiero suponer que el error es por que no he configurado correctamente el IIS o el archivo Web.config para que se conecte a la base de datos de SQL Server y pueda agregar los datos**

He intentado modificar el **Modelo de Identida** a **LocalSystem**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me salta un error de Controlador a la hora de ejecutar la pagina web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto el contenido de **Web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
       <add connectionString="Server=SQLServer;Database=AplicacioActivitats;User ID=victor;Password=victor" name="AprenGeografia" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".cshtml" mimeType="text/html" />
        </staticContent>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="Index.cshtml" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: DF59580E-4CAA-4F10-B02E-DEBE096AD379-->
```

Comment: Puedes mostrar el codigo de tu web.config para ayudarte

Comment: Una pregunta curiosa, has verificado que en tus servicios del sistema operativo el servicio `Sql Server` o `Sql Server (Sqlexpress)` este en ejecución?

Comment: Deberías mostrar lo que tienes en tu `Web.config`

Comment: Si estan en ejecucion. Ademas adjunto en la pregunta el contenido de Web.config.

Comment: @VictorMatillaSanchez hecha in vistazo aquí: [Error del servidor en la aplicación '/'. ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5890283/8933039) , [Error del servidor en la aplicación '/': error de inicio de sesión para el usuario](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343089/8933039) y esto : [Error del servidor en la aplicación '/'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4766389/8933039)

Comment: Al final lo que he echo es poner en "Default" la base de datos en el Web.config de tal manera que cuando alguien se baje mi codigo y quiera tener una base de datos, se le generara automaticamente en el SQL. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Desde el managment studio te conectas con esos mismos datos? En tu cadena de conexión van los mismos datos que ingresas en el managment studio.

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar esto, vaya al servidor `IIS` y luego al grupo de aplicaciones desde el que se ejecuta la aplicación. En la configuración avanzada del grupo de aplicaciones hay una opción de **"Modelo de proceso"** (`Process Model`), debajo de la cual hay una opción de **"Identidad"** (`Identity`).

Esto es por defecto la [identidad del grupo de aplicaciones](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities). Cambiarlo a `Sistema Local`, y listo. **Y recuerde poner la carpeta `App_Data` en la carpeta `WWW` del servidor `IIS`**

**Otra posible solución puede ser:**

Edite el archivo `applicationHost.config` que se encuentra en `%windir%\system32 \inetsrv\config\` específicamente en la sección `ApplicationPools`.

Cambie `IdentityType` a `NetworkService` para usar la base de datos recién creada.

```
<add name="ASP.NET v4.0" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
   <processModel identityType="NetworkService" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />
</add>
```

Vea tambíen:

- [¿Cuáles son todas las cuentas de usuario para IIS / ASP.NET y cómo difieren?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5731360/8933039) (Traducir del Inglés).

Comment: He seguido tus pasos y me sigue saliendo error, te adjunto en una respuesta el error que me sale.

Comment: @VictorMatillaSanchez cual es el error?

Comment: Te lo he añadido en una respuesta.

Comment: @VictorMatillaSanchez edita tu pregunta, y coloca la información no es correcto que lo comentes en una respuesta, si no es una respuesta que responda a tu propia pregunta.

Comment: Cierto, perdona, justo lo acabo de hacer.